# Fetching URL vars into form and submitting to other page

Tags: php, variables, url

I have this url: `torneioJogo.php?equipaleft=24&equiparight=25&torneioid=8`

The following code is in this url...

```
<form method='GET' action='torneioJogoSub.php?'>

//THESE INPUTS DOWN HERE
<input type="hidden" name="equipa1" value="<?php $_GET['equipaleft'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="equipa2" value="<?php $_GET['equiparight'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="torneioid" value="<?php $_GET['torneioid'] ?>">

<div id="pontos">
<input type="submit" name="win1" value="<=Vencedor">
<input type="submit" name="emp" value="Empate">
<input type="submit" name="win2" value="Vencedor=>">
<br>
<=Pontos=><br>

//AND THESE INPUTS DOWN HERE
<input type="text" name="pontos1" size="3">
<input type="text" name="pontos2" size="3">

<br>
</div>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, I need all the data from those inputs in the next page where I have this:

```
echo "equipa1: " . $_GET['equipa1'];
echo "equipa2: " . $_GET['equipa2'];
echo "torneioid: " . $_GET['torneioid'];
echo "pontos1: " . $_GET['pontos1'];
echo "pontos2: " . $_GET['pontos2'];
```

What happens is `$_GET['pontos2']` and `$_GET['pontos1']` work but the values from the hidden inputs (which are being pulled from the url variables), echo nothing. What's happening? Is this a problem with `GETs` and `POSTs` or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to echo the values out

```
<input type="hidden" name="equipa1" value="<?php echo $_GET['equipaleft'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="equipa2" value="<?php echo $_GET['equiparight'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="torneioid" value="<?php echo $_GET['torneioid'] ?>">
```

Comment: Lol, I'd actually already thought about that. I probably had to get up and do something else and forgot to put that in. Thx :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually output the variables into the form fields

```
<input type="hidden" name="equipa1" value="<?php echo $_GET['equipaleft'] ?>">
                                                 ^^^^
```